# Apache Spark Parquet: Cannot build an empty group

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I use Apache Spark 2.1.1 (used 2.1.0 and it was the same, switched today).
I have a dataset:

```
root
|-- muons: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- reco::Candidate: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- qx3_: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- pt_: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- eta_: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- phi_: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- mass_: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- vertex_: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- fCoordinates: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- fX: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- fY: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- fZ: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- pdgId_: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- status_: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- cachePolarFixed_: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- cacheCartesianFixed_: struct (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, there are 3 empty structs in this schema. I know 100% that I can read/manipulate/do whatever. However, when I try writing to disk in parquet, I get the following Exception:

```
dsReduced.write.format("parquet").save(outputPathName):

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build an empty group
at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:91)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$BaseGroupBuilder.build(Types.java:622)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$BaseGroupBuilder.build(Types.java:497)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$Builder.named(Types.java:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter.convertField(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:535)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter.convertField(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:321)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:534)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:533)
```

So, basically I would like to understand if it's a bug or an intended behavior??? I also assume that it's related to the empty structs. Any help would be really appreciated!

**Update: I've quickly created stripped version and that one works without any issues! Any insight would be really helpful!**

VK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Parquet does not write empty structs**:

for more info - see here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20593

VK

Comment: if you control the data source, like it was in my case, i removed all of the empty rows (nested ones as well)  before handing a row to spark.