# Why does streaming query fail with "InvalidSchemaException: A group type can not be empty (...) Empty group: spark_schema" while writing to parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.2.1 with Parquet 1.8.1.

I want to read JSON data from Kafka and do some transformation then write data into parquet files which can then be loaded by Apache Hive. But I met the following error when writeStream to parquet.

```
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException: A group type can not be empty. Parquet does not support empty group without leaves. Empty group: spark_schema
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.<init>(GroupType.java:92)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.<init>(GroupType.java:48)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType.<init>(MessageType.java:50)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$MessageTypeBuilder.named(Types.java:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.<init>(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.<clinit>(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala)
    ... 22 more
```

I googled and found the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767358/apache-spark-parquet-cannot-build-an-empty-group) met by other, the root cause of that is not all fields are leaf ones which parquet doesn't support, but here in my dataframe there are all leaf fields. Why? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```scala
  val nestTimestampFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"
  val jsonOptions: Map[String, String] = Map{ "timestampFormat" -> nestTimestampFormat }
  val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "wikipedia-edits")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("group.id", "SparkProcessor")
    .load()
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema, jsonOptions) as "wikiEdit")

  val parsed = df.select("wikiEdit.bot", "wikiEdit.title", "wikiEdit.user", "wikiEdit.wiki")

  parsed.printSchema()

  //parsed.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination(30000)

  parsed.writeStream.format("parquet")
    .option("path","hdfs://localhost:9000/wiki-parquet-spark")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://localhost:9000/checkpoint")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10*1000))
    .start.awaitTermination()
```

The program can print schema and show some data in the dataframe.

```
root
 |-- bot: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- wiki: string (nullable = true)

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+
|bot  |title                        |user      |wiki       |
+-----+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+
|false|Jak Roberto                  |WikiPedant|enwiki     |
|false|File:Oostkamp01.jpg          |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:CC-BY-SA-4.0        |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Self-published work |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Geography of Belgium|Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:CC-BY-SA-4.0        |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Self-published work |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Geography of Belgium|Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:CC-BY-SA-4.0        |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Self-published work |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Geography of Belgium|Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:CC-BY-SA-4.0        |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Self-published work |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Geography of Belgium|Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:CC-BY-SA-4.0        |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Self-published work |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|false|Category:Geography of Belgium|Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|true |Category:CC-BY-SA-4.0        |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|true |Category:Self-published work |Herpoel   |commonswiki|
|true |Category:Geography of Belgium|Herpoel   |commonswiki|
+-----+-----------------------------+----------+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: After upgrade parquet version from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 suggested, the issue fixed, thank you Jacek!

Comment: By the way, 
1. how to control each parquet file size? There are so many small files. 
2. how to add partition directory? I used partitionBy("user") but seemed no effect.

Comment: I'm confused...How did you do _"After upgrade parquet version from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 suggested"_? You said that you used Spark 2.2.1 with Parquet 1.8.1, but I thought that Spark as of 2.2.0 uses Parquet 1.8.2 so...please elaborate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Upgrade to Spark 2.2.0 (or even better to 2.2.1).

I *think* it is related to [PARQUET-363
Cannot construct empty MessageType for ReadContext.requestedSchema](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-363) that does mention the error message and Spark.

> In parquet-mr 1.8.1, constructing empty GroupType (and thus MessageType) is not allowed anymore (see PARQUET-278). This change makes sense in most cases since Parquet doesn't support empty groups. However, there is one use case where an empty MessageType is valid, namely passing an empty MessageType as the requestedSchema constructor argument of ReadContext when counting rows in a Parquet file. The reason why it works is that, Parquet can retrieve row count from block metadata without materializing any columns.

And later in the issue report:

> We can see that Spark SQL passes no requested columns to the underlying Parquet reader.

That issue report is linked to the [pull request #263](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/pull/263) that says:

> This removes the check added in PARQUET-278 that rejects schema groups
>   that have no fields. Selecting 0 columns from a file is allowed and used
>   by Hive and SparkSQL to implement queries like select count(1) ...

And the pull request does remove the check (that you've been facing in your streaming Dataset / Spark Structured Streaming).

```
throw new InvalidSchemaException("A group type can not be empty. Parquet does not support empty group without leaves. Empty group: " + name);
```

With that we learnt that the version of Parquet in Spark *may* have been different from the 1.8 release branch.

That leads to the discussion in the [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16281) that was eventually closed for the sake of another [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/26a4cba3ffaadf382ca14980378965704ccef9ab) that was accepted as part of bumping parquet version to **1.8.2**. And that's the version of Parquet we want to get rid of the error message.

Since Spark uses Parquet 1.8.2 as of Spark 2.2.0 my recommendation is to upgrade to Spark 2.2.0 (or even better to 2.2.1).